# Without using Dataframes can we sort the specific column

Tags: python, excel, pandas, sorting, dataframe

```
import pandas as pd
import xlwings as xw
import xlrd

PATH = r'C:\Users\user2\Desktop\Supplier Database.xlsx'
wb = xw.Book(PATH)  
data = pd.read_excel(r"C:\Users\user2\Desktop\Supplier Database.xlsx") 


data.sort_values("Weightpertrip(kg)", axis = 0, ascending = False, 
                 inplace = True,) 

array=[]
for i in range(2,12):
    array.append([data.cell(i,10).value])
print(array)
```

Without using Dataframes can we sort the specific column of Excel in Python